# Striations in Kundt's tube

Tags: waves, acoustics

Is there some modern calculation of the distances of the striations appearing when experimenting in a tube of Kundt with different powders (sand, cork, etc) sound frequencies and amplitudes?

Practically all the references I have found online seem to agree with, and point to, an explanation based in vortexes, published time ago in (now open access) http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/230/681-693/413. But while Andrade gives an empirical fit strong enough to discard other models, he does not seem to give a first-principles calculation for his own answer.

It has been almost one hundred years since this, so now I would hope that it is possible now to model the stripes in some computer, or even to provide an analytical formula. It could be a nice complement to an experiment that a lot of students perform in the secondary school lab.

Comment: What about https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.1934081 which is a paper I cannot access.

Comment: Same, it just forwards to Andrade's work. No new model nor new calculation of the exponent of the cosine.

Comment: I was curious, do you know if the stripes are caused by some kind of electrostatic force between styrofoam balls or it’s just air circulation? What did you mean by vortexes? Thanks!! @arivero

Comment: Relevant [paper](http://pub.dega-akustik.de/DAGA_1999-2008/data/articles/001612.pdf).